# Subheader list in sidemenu using Ionic Framework

Tags: angularjs, mobile, ionic-framework, ui-design

I am new to Ionic Framework.
I have a problem here. I need a subheader with list of two hyperlinks in a single side-menu
 like this.

[image: Design I need]

My Code :

```
   <ion-header-bar class="bar-header">
            <h5 class="align-left"> Hello, Niranth Reddy </h5>
           <h5 class="align-right"> <a href="" ng-click="signOut()">
            Sign Out    </a> </h5>                                                                         
        </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-subheader item-input-inset">
        <ion-item class="item-input-wrapper">
           <ul>
            <li>My Profile</li> 
            <li>My Orders</li>
           </ul>
         </ion-item>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
         <ion-list class="sideNav">
            <ion-item menu-toggle   
                ng-repeat="item in items track by $index"
                 class="side-menu item"
                   ng-click="getSelcected(item)"
                     href="#/sidemenu//{{item.name}}">
                         <div class="row">
                            <i class="{{item.link.icon}} featureIcon"></i>
                            <h4 class="col">{{item.properties.menuname}}</h4>
                        </div>
                    </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
         </ion-content>
```

Bu the result i get is like :

[image: Result I got]

Background colors doesn't matter. But I am specifically looking for such kind of design.

Any help guys ??

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to make changes in your code as follows.

Replace following code in your HTML

```
<ion-item class="item-input-wrapper">
  <ul>
     <li>My Profile</li> 
     <li>My Orders</li>
  </ul>
 </ion-item>
```

with,

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>My Profile</ion-item>
  <ion-item>My Orders</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

or with

```
<div class="list">
  <ion-item>My Profile</ion-item>
  <ion-item>My Orders</ion-item>
</div>
```

Second one will be efficient.

Comment: Forming a list now but, this is now overlapping existing list below.

Comment: That is because of placing list in subheader. Put it in content or change height of subheader in sidemenu  using CSS. Because, ionic sets .bar height to 44px.

Comment: Well, Placing it in ion-content instead of header or subheader works fine.

Comment: Ok. It would be nice.